# Python append array to the last column

Tags: python, dataframe

the below array is a result of my model, how to append it back to my dataframe's last column

```
In[]  logireg.predict(X.head(5))
Out[] array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

dataframe data:

```
age   job       month
33   blue       apr
56   admin      jun
37   tech       aug
76   retired    jun
56   service    may
```

expected output

```
age   job       month   predict
33   blue       apr       0
56   admin      jun       0
37   tech       aug       0
76   retired    jun       1
56   service    may       0
```

use for loop or zip function?

Comment: Simply assign it: `df['predict'] = logireg.predict(X.head(5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign it directly to a dataframe column. Assuming your dataframe is called `dataframe` here:

```
predictions = logireg.predict(X.head(5))
dataframe['predict'] = predictions
```

Comment: i get a warning message "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: I believe thats a separate issue and would refer more to how you got to the current state of your dataframe (i.e. did you do any manipulations on it?). You'll find a lot of questions about that warning on SO